# Mongo database in GCP app engine

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently looking into GCP [app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) and I was figuring out how I would deploy a very large application with multiple services. I also wanted to use mongodb. GCP docs say that app engine allows dockerfiles and images. What would happen if I used the mongo docker image as a service on app engine? How would it scale it's instances? What will happen to consistency? I'm aware GCP have a third party solution for mongo, but since they allow docker images, what stops me from using it?

Answer (score 2):

App Engine routinely tears down and creates new instances.  If your instance is running MongoDB, then all the data stored in that instance will be lost.

This is why Google Cloud offers other, permanent places to store state, like Datastore and CloudSQL.  You can also run MongoDb yourself on Google Compute Engine.

Comment: As @JeffreyRennie says, GAE instances are restarted frequently so you'll lose data. Here is the documentation for uptime in both [GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_uptime) and [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-instances-are-managed)

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if I used the mongo docker image as a service on app engine?

Flexible App Engine allows you to use docker images to build your own application, as per is mentioned on this document [1]: "App Engine flexible environment instances are Compute Engine virtual machines, which means that you can take advantage of custom libraries, use SSH for debugging, and deploy your own Docker containers."
So there is no problem to use your own docker image in flexible app Engine.

How would it scale it's instances?

Each active version in App Engine must have at least one instance to handle requests, there are two ways to scale the instance in App Engine: automatic and manual.

As per is mentioned on the document[2]: 
Automatic scaling creates instances based on request rate, response latencies, and other application metrics. You can specify thresholds for each of these metrics, as well as a minimum number instances to keep running at all times.
Manual scaling specifies the number of instances that continuously run regardless of the load level. This allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that rely on the state of the memory over time.
The way you can configure these features is through the app.yaml file, I suggest you read this document[3]

What will happen to consistency?

Since App Engine scaling can be configured depending on its load, this allows for good performance in service execution and provides consistency in operations and optimization of resources.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible#features
[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling
[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml